# Is there a way to shorten this for loop for adding to a byte array?

Tags: python

```
packed_vertices = bytearray()

for vertex in stacked_vertices:
    packed_vertices += (
        struct.pack(">" + "f" * 3, vertex[0], vertex[1], vertex[2])
        + b"\x00\x00\x00\xFF"
    )
```

Is there a way to make this more compact and shorten the amount of lines of code? I'm currently working on a project, and I'm trying to reduce the amount of code. Instead of doing a for loop, is there a shorter, faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you could probably get away with something like

```
b"".join(map(lambda vertex: struct.pack(">" + "f" * 3, vertex[0], vertex[1], vertex[2]) + b"\x00\x00\x00\xFF", stacked_vertices))
```

But that is not very readable. Being verbose is not a bad thing so I would personally define the lambda as an actual function, maybe even call it `pack_vertex` and end up with something like:

```
def pack_vertex(vertex):
    return struct.pack(">" + "f" * 3, vertex[0], vertex[1], vertex[2]) + b"\x00\x00\x00\xFF"

b"".join(map(pack_vertex, stacked_vertices))
```